# Type error when doing a seemingly normal division in python

Tags: python, function, types, typeerror, division

```
return sp.integrate.quad(int_jean, R, 10) / R
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'tuple' and 'int'
```

The `1 / R` appears to be causing the error but I cannot see why. It should just be dividing by a float. I plot the integrand and it looks ok.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy as sp
import numpy as np

def nu(r):
    return 1 / r

def int_jean(r):
    return nu(r) / r**2

def rms(R):
    return sp.sqrt( 3 * sp.integrate.quad(int_jean, R, 10) / R


print(rms(5))

t1 = np.arange(0.1, 10.0, 0.01)
m = list(map(int_jean, t1))
print(m)
plt.plot(t1, m)
plt.show()
```

Comment: The TypeError is fairly explicit about the problem ... `quad` is returning a tuple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**quad**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html) returns a tuple.  You cannot divide an entire tuple by a float.  Perhaps you mean to divide the value of the integral.  You need to grab that return element only, the first member:

```
return sp.integrate.quad(int_jean, R, 10)[0] / R
```

Answer (score 0):

A cursory glance at the documentation tells us that [`scipy.integrate.quad`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html) returns a tuple of the integral and an estimate of the absolute error.

Presumably, you are wanting to do:

```
def rms(R):
    return sp.sqrt( 3 * sp.integrate.quad(int_jean, R, 10)[0] / R)
```

(Note, you are missing a bracket in your original code)